# Access AngularJS constant in a view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I'm gonna try to describe the scenario, bear with me please.

I have a Angular constant called Urls filled with the routes and some methods to access them.

```coffeescript
app = angular.module "app"

app.constant "Urls",
    routes: 
        # Main stuff
        overview: "/"
        users: "/users"
        user: "/users/:id"

    overview: ->
        return @.routes.overview
    users: ->
        return @.routes.users
    user: (id)->
        return @.routes.user
                    .replace(":id", id)
```

The reason for using a constant for this is that I need to access it during the config phase of our application as well as use it in controllers.

What I want to achieve is that I want to use it in a view as well, for instance;

```html
<ul class="foo">
    <li ng-repeat="user in users">
        <a href="{{Urls.user(user.id)}}">
            {{user.name}}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to achieve something like this? Preferably without assigning the Urls constant to $rootScope or assigning it to every controllers $scope?

Comment: You need to inject `Urls` in controller.

Comment: @Satpal, right, what I'm asking is if theres a way to get away from that. Or are you telling me it's actually impossible?

Comment: I assume that's coffesscript you're using there. You might get more help if you use plain javascript.

Comment: I don't understand how that would be relevant whatsoever. I think I've been pretty clear of what I want to achieve. If someone knows the answer I hope they will help me regardless if I'm writing application logic in Coffeescript or plain ol' Javascript

Comment: The simplest way I know is to use $rootScope, the cleaner way the injection in a controller. You must assign Urls to a scope if you want  to use it in a view.

Answer (score 11):

Is not possible. You need to inject `Urls` in the controller `$scope` (or parent using `$parent`) because `{{ var }}` is interpolated to `$scope.var`

Does not have any performance problem if you inject `Urls` in your controller and write `$scope.Urls = Urls`

Example:

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('myController', ($scope, Urls) {
  $scope.Urls = Urls;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that there's no performance hit?  Even a small one?  The way I understand it, anything attached to $scope will be dirty checked during Angular's digest cycle.

Comment: I prefer to set shared vars or functions to `$rootScope`, just like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19381225/angularjs-common-controller-functionality-mix-in-where-needed-or-define-on-ro